# vsvars32.bat missing, Error while trying to building a Python program with Nuitka

Tags: python, c++, windows, compilation, nuitka

I've got a little script that I want to compile using Nuitka. So I installed Nuitka, then I installed minGW C++ compiler, Nuitka then asked me to install python 2.7, so I installed that as well.

Running `nuitka recursive-all program.py` results in a large unreadable stack trace.
It starts with
`"vsvars32.bat" is not recognized as an internal or external command.`

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `vsvars32.bat` is a Visual Studio script. Maybe Nuitka is configured to use VS instead of GCC? Did you try to pass `--mingw` to Nuitka?

Comment: @cubuspl42 No, I didn't try that. I thought that nuitka would automatically find what compiler to use, since it said something along the lines of "install one of these four compilers ... if you install mingw to C:\mingw it will be automatically found".

I'm still getting some compiler errors, but at least it's not this one.

Comment: If you don't have VS installed, and Nuitka sees g++ after passing `--mingw`, than it seems like a bug, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @cubuspl42 I wasn't clear enough, no, I didn't use `--mingw`. After using the `--mingw` flag, this error dissappeared. The other errors I have now are related to that I use python 3.4, which is only partially supported. I'll try Python 3.3 now.

Comment: You was clear enough. I'm just saying that Nuitka (AFAIK) *shouldn't try* to use VS if it's not installed on the system. `--mingw` flag's purpose seems to be overriding VS with MinGW, not choosing MinGW when there is no VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really simple. I haven't figured out how to build properly yet, but the issue was, as cubuspl42 said, that nuitka was configured to compile with visual studio as default.

`nuitka recursive-all --mingw program.py`

Comment: If this is your final answer, please mark it. Yes, even if you answered it yourself.

Comment: @hazzey you can only accept your own answer after two days.